# Why is bayes theorem formula always presented in the hard-to-remember way?

Tags: bayesian, teaching

$P(B|A)\cdot P(A) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$

would be so much more intuitive to understand and thus easier to remember.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What intuition does that give you?

Comment: I guess OP has a point that it's quick to write down this way since everything is symmetric.  I wouldn't call it more intuitive per se, but agree that this is easier to remember w/o thinking too much about details of formula and it's meaning/implications.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a question of psychology, not statistics.

Answer (score 2):

You have the tag "Bayesian", so I just thought I'd mention the centrality of the posterior distribution $P(B|A)$ (where $B$ is an unknown parameter and $A$ the data) to Bayesian inference.

In other words, it's because $P(B|A)$ tends to be the thing we care about.

Comment: I can get on board with this: we care about $P(B\vert A)$, so write the formula to give that value of interest.